# background_locator_2 not working properly in apk?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, geolocation

I'm using background_locator_2 to develop an application that takes routes, with a start route and stop route button. In the emulator the application is working and taking the routes, but when it generates the apk and I try to test it, it does not work. Can anyone tell me what could be going on? why are the routes not picking up in the apk?

Comment: Can you provide some code, your question seems unclear.